# IntelliJ header not showing up on new Java project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, header

**Problem Statement**

First time IntelliJ user, newish Computer Science student...
I am trying to include a header when I create a new `Java project`. So far I have gone to `settings > Editor > File and Code Templates > Includes >` and I have created a header. However when I start a new command line project, no header shows up.

I'm guessing there is something else I have to do but I can't figure it out. What else needs to be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "start a new command line project"? Also, please check that you really changed File Header and not, for example, ActionScript File Header.

Comment: When I create a new project in java there is the option to check a box that will create a new command line project which consists of throwing in the main method for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the "Create project from template" option, the header will not be applied to files from the template. You can simply create an empty project (don't check the "Create project from template") and then create a new class. The result will be the same, but your header will be applied correctly.